# MonoTouch / MonoDevelop: "Did not get project info" when opening xib-files

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

So, I just installed everything needed for MonoTouch on a MacBook running Lion.

I followed the steps/instructions to install (see [here](http://blong.com/Articles/CSharpMonoTouch5/MonoTouch.htm#Gettingstarted)) and then created a new solution. When I open my xib-file I get the following error (in MonoDevelop):

> Error updating Objective-C type information. Did not get project info
>        System.Exception: Did not get project info
>         at MonoDevelop.Macdev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.UpdateTypes(IProgressMonitor monitor, Boolean force) [0x00029 in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-2.8.6.4/ca00645c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeProjectTracker.cs:351

I have done nothing else than installiong Xcode, then the Framework/Runtime (MRE-2.10.8_3), then MonoDevelop (2.8.6.4) and then MonoTouch.

Anyone seen this before? I can't find a single thing in this specific error on the net.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that I needed to close the solution, restart the program and then some form of "updating xcode"-thing was running. Then it worked with getting the designer up. Of course, I can't see the Assistant Editor and create those outlets, but that's another issue...

Comment: Strange. You shouldn't need to restart MonoDevelop after creating a new project. To see the assistant editor in Xcode, click on the icon in the upper-right that looks like a tuxedo.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the h-files isn't created. I have posted another question on that as you have seen =)

Comment: The exception you are getting here is a legitimate bug in MonoDevelop. We asynchronously parse the project source files to get a database of types and their methods. If you try to launch Xcode too early, you can get that exception... but we really need to make it impossible to get it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by building the application, and then double clicking the xib file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by building the application, closing and reopening the solution, and then double clicking the xib file.